# Wrapping FILE* with custom std::ostream

Tags: c++, wrapper, iostream

I have a function which works with a `std::ostream`. I need to support using a *C file handle* (`FILE*`). Should I be creating *my own subclass* of `std::ostream` which delegates to a `FILE*`?

Comment: If you want to go nuts and change it back, go ahead. Nothing about wrapping things with classes, or FILE* inherited and standardized separately from C makes it a C question. As Stackoverflow-ers love to point out, C is not a subset of C++.

Comment: See [this](http://ilab.usc.edu/rjpeters/groovx/classrutz_1_1stdiobuf.html) subclass of `streambuf` that wraps `FILE*`.

Comment: @Kazark: Awesome... If you post that as an answer I'd accept it :)

Comment: Note that this is related to the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746168/how-to-construct-a-c-fstream-from-a-posix-file-descriptor

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Ben Voigt points out, you want to subclass `streambuf`. There are pages on the University of Southern California's website which have the [documentation](http://ilab.usc.edu/rjpeters/groovx/classrutz_1_1stdiobuf.html), [header](http://ilab.usc.edu/rjpeters/groovx/stdiobuf_8h-source.html), and [source](http://ilab.usc.edu/rjpeters/groovx/stdiobuf_8cc-source.html) for a GNU implementation of a `streambuf` subclass (`stdiobuf`) that wraps a `FILE*`. It has some dependencies on the library it is a part of (GroovX), but those should be easily to remove (I would begin by removing all references to `GVX_TRACE`).

Interestingly, it also provides a minimalistic subclass (`stdiostream`) of `std::iostream`, in spite of what Ben Voigt said. But this does not seem to be necessary, as the [rdbuf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/rdbuf/) ("read buffer"/set the stream buffer) method which the `stdiostream` class uses to connect the `stdiobuf` class to a stream object is publicly accessible.

You can find more about subclassing `streambuf` [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/streambuf/streambuf/) (look particularly at the bottom of the page, which discussing the virtual functions). The implementation linked above overrides [`sync`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/streambuf/streambuf/sync/), [`underflow`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/streambuf/streambuf/underflow/) (to support input) and [`overflow`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/streambuf/streambuf/overflow/) (to support output).

Further notes about the linked implementation:

- The `init` method uses the [`setg`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/streambuf/streambuf/setg/) and [`setp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/streambuf/streambuf/setp/) methods to set the pointers for the input and output sequences.
- The line `const int num = pptr()-pbase();` is calculating the number of characters to flush by subtracting the [base output pointer](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/streambuf/streambuf/pbase/) from the [current output pointer](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/streambuf/streambuf/pptr/) ("put pointer").
- The variable unhelpfully named `om` is the mode parameter.
- The variable named `fd` is the file descriptor.

Answer (score 6):

No, `ostream` is not meant to be derived from.  The way the iostreams library allows customization is by supplying a `streambuf` pointer when creating an `ostream`.  `streambuf` has a lot of virtual functions so you can change its behavior.

You need to derive either directly from `streambuf` or from the existing `filebuf` subclass.  You probably only need to provide the `overflow` function, the defaults for all the others should work ok.

Comment: Wow that actually sounds halfway clean.

Comment: Well, iostreams is designed to be extensible.  A week or so ago, I wrote one `stingbuf` to allow data written to `cout` to show up in a UI textbox when there was no console window attached (just overrode `sync`), and also an input `streambuf` subclass using memory-mapped files and which was in the neighborhood of 20-30 times faster than the `ifstream`+`getline`+`istringstream` I had been used for textfile processing.  It's really amazing how inefficient the standard streambuf implementations are, because they try to fit every possible scenario.

Comment: Actually, it's perfectly OK to derive from `ostream`, see for instance `ofstream`. However, such derived classes just provide a convenenience ctor that calls `ostream::ostream(streambuf*)`.