# Can I use a FILE* to initialize a C++ ostream object?

Tags: c++, stream, iostream

Can I use an elsewhere opened

```
FILE* f = ...
```

thing to initialize some `std::ostream` instance? Like this (pseudocode):

```
FILE *f = ...;
std::ostream os;
os./*bind_to_f*/( f );    // HOW?
os << "Hello world" << std::endl;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wrapping FILE* with custom std::ostream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151504/wrapping-file-with-custom-stdostream)

Comment: @GSerg: Ben Voigt's answer certainly seems to answer this question too.

Comment: Not an exact dup, but informational: http://stackoverflow.com/q/109449/14065

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746168/how-to-construct-a-c-fstream-from-a-posix-file-descriptor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GCC you can just pass the existing file descriptor to the constructor ([ref](http://www.slac.stanford.edu/comp/unix/gnu-info/iostream_4.html)):

```
FILE *f = ...;
std::ofstream os(fileno(f));
```

> Constructor: ofstream::ofstream (int fd)
>
> Make an ofstream for writing to a file that was already open, using file descriptor fd.

Comment: `FILE*` isn't a file descriptor.

Comment: And using a file descriptor isn't standard, so I would advise against anything like this.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: Woops, but `fileno(FILE*)` returns the fd from the file.

Comment: @John: This is GCC only, so no need to worry about the regular standard. Though I would prefer an all-standard solution too.

Comment: actually, I think I want to try this. I like portable code as well, yes, but in this case it might save me a couple of hundred lines. How bad can it be? http://xkcd.com/292/ ;-)

Comment: How do you close this properly? You have two objects (`FILE *` and `ofstream`) referring to the same file descriptor. Although you might just want to ignore the error. But an `fclose(f)` is necessary to free memory and will interact with the `ofstream`. A call to `dup()` might help.

Answer (score 4):

`FILE*` and streams are C and C++ style I/O capabilities respectively. Since the C++ library doesn't always know about the implementation of the underlying C library there's no way to do this. Additionally consider, what would the ownership semantics be if you could do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you were to create a streambuf class that used a FILE* internally, you could do it.  For example, [HP OpenVMS](http://h71000.www7.hp.com/commercial/cplus/vax_doc/clv006.htm#stdiobufclass) seems to have a class like that.