# How to change FIFE* to fstream

Tags: c++, file, fstream

I have used `popen` function to get a `FIFE* fp`, but now I want to use `std::fstream` to read from `fp`.

How can I create connection from `fp` to `std::fstream`?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151504

Comment: The `f` in `std::fstream` stands for "file" not "flute", so there is no way to connect a `FIFE*` to it.