# How to get MFC serialization going without a CWinApp-derived class?

Tags: visual-c++, serialization, mfc, c++-cli, clr

I am writing a C++/CLI wrapper for an old MFC application, so far i have been able to read most of the data and convert the same into C# readable format.

As of now i am only struggling with reading data and am worried will writing data back to old MFC code affect serialization ?

Can you guys share/mention any other risks i might face while writing C++/CLI wrapper for MFC code ?

Thanks for your inputs.

this question is a continuation of "[Redirecting data from MFC CArchive to boost::archive::xml_oarchive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37530356/redirecting-data-from-mfc-carchive-to-boostarchivexml-oarchive)" Please go through this if you need more details. and do let me know if you need more information from me.

Comment: A relevant snippet of the code that you have now would help, along with a details of the error message you are getting.

Comment: @sevatitov titov array<unsigned long ^>^ test;  i read data from DWORD array convert it to "unsigned long" but when i pass the value to "test" array it says, arguments are wrong, array expects "System:uint32"  but i am passing "unsigned long".

Comment: Can you add snippet of code to your question? It is really difficult to read unformatted code embedded into a text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the experience i had with this is, as long as we do not change existing "class/structure definitions" and "variable definitions",  object serialization is not affected.