# Creating fstream object from a FILE* pointer

Tags: c++, popen, ifstream

The well known way of creating an **`fstream`** object is:

```
ifstream fobj("myfile.txt");
```

ie. using a filename.

But I want to create an ifstream object using a file descriptor.

> **Reason:** I want to execute a command using `_popen()`**.** `_popen()` returns the output as a `FILE*`. So there is a FILE* pointer involved but no filename.

Comment: @Joe: Posix file descriptors are yet another thing. Presumably, both C++ iostreams and C I/O are implemented in terms of them on a Posix platform. The present question is more reasonable, though, since both iostreams *and* C I/O are part of the standard library.

Comment: this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746168/how-to-construct-a-c-fstream-from-a-posix-file-descriptor given you can use `fileno` on the `FILE*` returned from `popen`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot do that just in standard C++, since iostreams and C I/O are entirely separate and unrelated. You could however write your *own* iostream that's backed by a C FILE stream. I believe that GCC comes with one such stream class as a library extension.

Alternatively, if all you want is an object-y way of wrapping a C FILE stream, you could [use a unique pointer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4679/shared-ptr-and-file-for-wrapping-cstdio-update-also-dlfcn-h) for that purpose.

Comment: Basically I want to read _popen()'s output into a single string. A little research led me to fstream. Please suggest something to that context.

Comment: @ahmedtabrez: Just go with `std::fread` as usual; use an intermediate buffer and append the bytes you read to your result string. Or look into those GCC extensions.

Comment: Please, can we discuss here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11467/room-for-ahmedtabrez-and-kerrek-sb

Answer (score 0):

You can try QTextStream.

See in https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtextstream.html#QTextStream-2

Comment: Did he say he was Qt friendly? Question says NIMBY.

Answer (score -3):

You can create a string, and use fread to read and append to it. It's not clean, but you're working with a C interface.

Something like this should work:

```
FILE * f = popen(...)
const unsigned N=1024;
string total;
while (true) {
    vector<char> buf[N];
    size_t read = fread((void *)&buf[0], 1, N, f);
    if (read) { total.append(buf.begin(), buf.end()); }
    if (read < N) { break; }
}
pclose(f);
```