# C++ to python communication. Multiple io streams?

Tags: python, process, communication, iostream

A python program opens a new process of the C++ program and is reading the processes stdout.
No problem so far.

But is it possible to have multiple streams like this for communication? I can get two if I misuse stderr too, but not more. Easy way to hack this would be using temporary files. Is there something more elegant that does not need a detour to the filesystem?

PS: *nix specific solutions are welcome too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On unix systems; the usual way to open a subprocess is with `fork()`, which will leave any open file descriptors (small integers representing open files or sockets) available in both the child, and the parent, and then `exec()`, which also allows the new executable to use the file descriptors that were open in the old process.  This functionality is preserved in the `subprocess.Popen()` call (adjustable with the `close_fds` argument).  Thus, what you probably want to do is use `os.pipe()` to create pairs of sockets to communicate on, then use `Popen()` to launch the other process, with arguments for each of fd's returned by the previous call to `pipe()` to tell it which fd's it should use.

Comment: If you go with this approach, you may want to look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746168/how-to-construct-a-c-fstream-from-a-posix-file-descriptor) for how to deal with the fd's on the C++ side.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you want are to use sockets for communication. Both languages let open raw sockets but you might want to check out the [zeromq](http://www.zeromq.org/) project as well which has some addition advantages for message passing. Check out their hello world in [c++](http://zguide.zeromq.org/cpp%3ahwclient) and [python](http://zguide.zeromq.org/py%3ahwclient).

Answer (score 0):

assuming windows machine.
you could try using the clipboard for exchanging information between python processes and C++.

assign some unique process id followed by your information and write it to clipboard on python side.....now just parse the string on C++ side.
its akin to using temporary files but all done in memory..... but the drawback being you cannot use clipboard for any other application.
hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

With traditional, synchronous programming and the standard Python library, what you're asking is difficult to accomplish. If, instead, you consider using an asynchronous programming model and the [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) library, it's a piece of cake. The [Using Processes HOWTO](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/process.html) describes how to easily communicate with as many processes as you like. Admittedly, there's a bit of a learning curve to Twisted but it's well worth the effort.