# Is the move constructor of ifsteam implicitly deleted?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11

I have the following simple class:

```
class Source
{
public:
    Source() = default;
    Source(Source const&) = delete;
    Source(Source&&) = default;

    explicit Source(std::string const& fileName)
     : inputStream(fileName), path_(fileName)
    {}

    ~Source() = default;

    auto path() const -> std::string
    {
        return this->path_;
    }

    std::ifstream inputStream;
private:
    std::string path_;
};

auto main(int argc, char* argv[]) -> int
{
    Source source(Source("test.txt"));
    cout << source.path() << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream) `ifstream` has a `move` constructor, but when I try to compile that with `MinGW 4.7.2`, I get the following error:

> ..\src\main.cpp:32:46: error: use of deleted function
>   'cy::Source::Source(cy::Source&&)' In file included from
>   ..\src\main.cpp:10:0: source.hpp:28:5: note:
>   'cy::Source::Source(cy::Source&&)' is implicitly deleted because the
>   default definition would be ill-formed: source.hpp:28:5: error: use of
>   deleted function 'std::basic_ifstream::basic_ifstream(const
>   std::basic_ifstream&)'
>   c:\mingw\bin../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/include/c++/fstream:420:11:
>   note: 'std::basic_ifstream::basic_ifstream(const
>   std::basic_ifstream&)' is implicitly deleted because the default
>   definition would be ill-formed:
>   c:\mingw\bin../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/include/c++/fstream:420:11:
>   error: use of deleted function
>   'std::basic_istream::basic_istream(const
>   std::basic_istream&)'

Am I doing something wrong? Or the documentation of cppreference is inaccurate? Or GCC 4.7.2 has a bug?

Comment: Move constructor is not deleted, copy-constructor is deleted.

Comment: Try Source source(Source("source.txt")); Even though your current code is equivalent, I believe there is a requirement that the operator= be accessible or something.

Comment: @SethCarnegie, thanks for your tip, but it didn't work either, gcc still says that move constructor is implicitly deleted.

Comment: I don't have access to a computer now but you could check the definition of ifstream in your header files and see if it really has a move ctor. If not, it's a gcc bug.Maybe try moving an ifstream by itself and see if gcc is erroneously not using it when it's a member.

Comment: It just hasn't been implemented yet, [see here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html). All the streams are `Missing move and swap operations`.

Comment: Thank you very much @JesseGood. That was something I wasn't expecting that the gcc standard library streams were missing move and swap. I will have to think in a workaround for my classes.

Comment: Using a `std::unique_ptr<std::ifstream>` is one workaround.

Comment: I don't want to heap-allocate a std::ifstream object. I will try to change my design (which is a more challenging task :D), so I don't need a move constructor. If I can't, then I think I will use your suggestion of using std::unique_ptr.

Comment: Why don't you want to heap allocate the stream? If the reason is performance it's unlikely to be a noticable difference over creating the stream itself (getting a file handle is quite expensive).

Comment: If it move was supported, you would get heap allocation anyway to facilitate move.

Comment: @JohanLundberg, what do you mean with if move was supported I would get heap allocation anyway? One thing is where ifstream allocate its internal data and other thing is where I allocate my ifstream object.

Comment: @Rayniery The typical way to support fast move is to hold all data by (smart) pointer. The pointer points to the data (normally on the heap [although you can in principle have memory on the stack reserved for this, with a custom allocator.]) Let's say all data in a stream is held by a single non-movable member variable m_data of type StreamImplType. To make the class movable, we could just use a member std::unique_ptr<StreamImplType>. 
Have a look at rule-of-zero: http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/2012/08/15/rule-of-zero.html

Comment: @SethCarnegie: It's true that `Type x = val;` and `Type x(val);` are different, but neither one involves `operator=` at all.  (For more, see the many questions on copy-initialization and direct-initialization.)

Comment: @aschepler yes I know, I meant that it was the same except something has to be accessible (and non-explicit), turns out it's the copy constructor. That's why I said "or something".

Comment: AFAICS, move-version of copy ctor implemented since GCC 5.0.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It turns out that the standard library implementation of GCC has not implemented yet the move and swap operation for the stream classes. See [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#iso.2011.specific) for detail about the current status of C++11 features in the gcc standard library.

Thanks [Jesse Good](https://stackoverflow.com/users/906773/jesse-good) for giving the information and link.

Comment: I +1'd the answer because it makes sense, but I couldn't find any reference to it in the referenced document.

Comment: @Carneiro, look more closer, it's there: '27.5 Iostreams base classes, Partial, Missing move and swap operations on basic_ios.'

Answer (score 1):

I realise this answer is a little bit late but to give an unmoveable class move sematics you could write a very simple wrapper class. For example:

```
#include <memory>



template <typename T>
class swap_wrapper
{
    //! internal buffer to hold object (on heap)
    std::unique_ptr<T> p_obj;
public:
    //! allows any of objects constructors to be called directly
    template <typename... Args>
    explicit swap_wrapper(Args&&... args)
        :   p_obj(
                     new T( std::forward<Args>(args)... )
                     ) {    }

    //! swaps pointer value of T object is unchanged therefore this 
    //! function puts no requirement on base class.

    //! note p_obj is left as a nullptr so dereferencing will cause
    //! undefined behaviour.
    swap_wrapper (swap_wrapper &&other) noexcept
        : p_obj(nullptr)
    {
        swap(other);
    }

    //! swaps pointer like above,
    //! T object is not touched; just the pointer.
    swap_wrapper &operator = (swap_wrapper &&other) noexcept
    {
        swap(other);
        return *this;
    }

    //! uses swap member function of std:unique_ptr
    void swap(swap_wrapper &other) noexcept
    {
        std::swap(p_obj, other.p_obj);
    }

    //! operators to allow access to stream
    T& operator *() { return *p_obj; }
    T const& operator *() const { return *p_obj; }

    T * operator ->() { return p_obj.get(); }
    T const * operator ->() const { return p_obj.get(); }

};


//! overload of default swap (calls member function swap)
template <typename S>
inline void swap(swap_wrapper<S> &one, swap_wrapper<S> &two) noexcept
{ one.swap(two); }
```

This wrapper can then be returned from functions, passed as an rvalue parameter, etc..