# Why can't I emplace ifstreams in a vector?

Tags: c++, c++11

The following example program doesn't compile for me on either
clang 3.1 or gcc 4.8:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<ifstream> bla;
    bla.emplace_back("filename");
    return 0;
}
```

However, I thought emplace_back should

> "Insert a new element at the end of the vector, right after its
>   current last element. This new element is constructed in place using
>   args as the arguments for its construction."

Does anyone know why this doesn't compile then? did I misunderstand or are the library implementations not yet complete?

Comment: I dont know C++, but do you judjing by your includes you have a typo at vector<ifstream>. Do you mean vector<fstream>? Please correct me if i am mistaken.

Comment: Elements of `std::vector` must be copyable, fstreams are not.

Comment: `ifstream` is a valid type defined in the `fstream` include.

Comment: @n.m. not true. Movable is the requirement.

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: I tried changing your `emplace_back()` to a `push_back(std::move(foo))`, and GCC 4.7.3 gave me an internal compiler error and crashed.  Yay.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I stand corrected.

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14640704/398060) mentions that in some versions of gcc the move and swap operations are not implemented for stream classes.  Perhaps your version is missing support?

Comment: If `std::deque` will do instead of `std::vector`, that will workaround the library bug.

Comment: Works fine with clang++/libc++

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Streams in c++11 are movable, so in theory you should be able to do what you want, problem is that movable streams have not yet been implemented in gcc/libstdc++.

To back up my answer further please take a look at gcc/libstdc++ c++11 status:
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011

Especially 27.5, 27.8, 27.9

Answer (score 7):

That's a bug in the implementation of `std::basic_istream`. It should be movable, but isn't; and only movable types can be stored in a vector.

[Here is the bug report against GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53626).

Comment: Thanks, that explains then.

Shouldn't you also be able to store copyable types in a vector though, even if they aren't moveable?

Comment: @dgel: streams aren't copyable, either (neither in C++98 or C++11).

Comment: @HighCommander4: I know, but I was commenting on his general statement that 'only movable types can be stored in a vector', which may be confusing.

Comment: @dgel: Copyable types *are* movable. "Movable" means that you can create an object that's the same as an existing object (possibly invalidating the existing object); "Copyable" means you can do that without changing the existing object.

Comment: @Mike Seymour: Thanks, I thought movable meant that it implemented move semantics, whereas a copyable type might not implement the relevant move-related functions.

Answer (score 0):

Since it isn't fixed yet (AFAIK), here's a quick workaround:

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<std::ifstream> SharedIFS;
inline SharedIFS MakeIFS(const std::string &file) {
    return SharedIFS(new std::ifstream(file));}
```

Unless I missed something stupid, the SharedIFS should be moveable and copyable just fine. It has some overhead compared to plain emplace_back, but at least you *can* put it into a vector.