# Open an ifstream on a pipe with no data without blocking

Tags: c++, named-pipes, fstream, ifstream

I am trying to use an ifstream to open a named pipe that will eventually have data written to it.

```
std::cout << "Opening " << name << std::endl;
std::ifstream manual_shutdown_file(name.c_str());
std::cout << "Opened " << name << std::endl;
```

When I run the program, it blocks in the `ifstream` constructor.  I see "Opening name" printed to the console, but the opened statement does not appear.

I know that I am connecting to the pipe, because if I execute

```
$ echo foo > name
```

from a shell, then the constructor returns and the Opened statement is printed.  Is there no way to open a pipe until it has data in it, even if I do not want to immediately try reading it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `open` on the read end of a pipe will block until the write end is opened.

You can use the `O_NONBLOCK` flag to open the file descriptor for the pipe, but there is no standard way to then use the fd with `std::ifstream`, [see here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746168/how-to-construct-a-c-fstream-from-a-posix-file-descriptor)

Guessing at your requirement, I'd say a small class that opens the fd and presents a polling signal interface would suit, something like:

```
namespace blah
{
class signal_t
{
private:
   int fd;

   // note: define sensible copy/move semantics
   signal_t(const signal_t&) = delete;
   signal_t& operator=(const signal_t&) = delete;
public:
   signal_t(const char* named_pipe);   // open fd, set O_NONBLOCK

   void notify() const;                // write 1 byte to fd as signal
   bool poll() const;                  // attempt to read from fd, return true if signalled.

   ~signal_t();                        // close fd
};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since opening an input pipe via `ifstream` blocks until there is someone writing to it, you could always just let the `ifstream` block. Then to unblock it from another thread create your own `ofstream` to that same pipe then immediately close the `ofstream`. This will unblock the `ifstream` and have it marked with `eof`. This is much easier and less error prone than messing with the platform specific controls of the file handles.

Answer (score -1):

You actually can open a `std::ifstream` on a named pipe without blocking for a writer, but you must set the flags as though you were also going to write to the stream.

Try `std::ifstream pipe_stream(filename, std::ifstream::in | std::ifstream::out)`, or `stream.open(filename, std::ifstream::in | std::ifstream::out)`.

Comment: From man 3 open "O_RDWR  Open  for reading and writing. The result is undefined if this flag is applied to a FIFO."
I guess in c++ opening a file in read & write mode will do the same thing