# Using popen as a substitue for "write to file" then "use ifstream to read from it" c++

Tags: c++, fstream, popen

I am a beginner so please be undertanding if the question is about sth obvious.

The current version of code is shown below. The output.txt is opened using ifstream and then fed to object of type Coll which is used because it understands "understands" the format of output.txt file generated.

```
std::system("./Pogram > output.txt");
Coll inputout;
    ifstream ifsout("output.txt");
    ifsout >> inputout;
```

My objective is to get rid of the intermediate output.txt and do sth like shown below.

```
FILE * f = popen("./Program", "r");
Coll inputout;
f >> inputout;
```

This yields the following error though:

```
error: no match for ‘operator>>’ in ‘f >> inputout’
```

Can you suggest any remedy to that?

Comment: A bit unusual, but if you really wanted your example code to work then you *could* implement `operator>>(FILE*, const Coll&)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `popen` only provides a `FILE *`, and I don't believe there is any (portable, reliable) way to convert that into a file-stream. So you will have to deal with using `fgets` to read a line as a C string and `stringstream` to convert it to your type, or using `fscanf` or similar.

Comment: I think you're right, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746168/how-to-construct-a-c-fstream-from-a-posix-file-descriptor might help depending how portable the questioner needs the code to be.

Comment: You can always create your own std::streambuf to read from FILE*... but that might be overkill

Comment: Yeah, unless you REALLY need to do this a lot - in which case creating a 'pipe' stream would be a better choice, I feel.

Comment: Thanks for all replies. Suggested methods didn't work, so I did brute-force by creating and added a "delete the temporary file" command at the end of code:      std::system("rm output.txt")

Answer (score 1):

May be this could work with [pstream](http://pstreams.sourceforge.net/) :

```
#include <pstream.h>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
  redi::ipstream proc("./Program");
  typedef std::istreambuf_iterator<char> it;
  std::string output(it(proc.rdbuf()), it());

  Coll inputout; 
  output>>inputout; // You might have overloaded  ">>"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`f` is of type `FILE` which does not have an `>>` operator.  You need to use things like `fread()` and `fwrite()`.  You also don't get all the fancy type conversions that ifstream lends to you, if you are to use `FILE` you basically have to read and write directly in bits.

```
fread(&inputout, sizeof(Coll), 1, f);
```

This is reading memory from the current file location and putting it into the variable `inputout` that is the size of a Coll x 1.

Comment: That only works if the data is binary, and the first example code shows it using `>>` which is not used in binary file reads.