# Why does clang let me take a temporary by non-const reference in C++03 mode?

Tags: c++, clang

[Inspired by my observation in a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25819841/while-loop-causing-an-infinite-loop-but-i-cant-figure-out-why#comment40391966_25819841), I decided to do a little test:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
  char c = 'A';
  std::stringstream ss("B");

  // I know this is bad mojo; that's why I'm testing it
  ss >> char(c);

  std::cout << c << std::endl;
}
```

My compiler version:

> `Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)`
>   `Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0`
>   `Thread model: posix`

Compiling clang in C++03 mode, it compiles and runs okay:

```
$ clang++ -Wall -pedantic -std=c++03 test.cpp 
test.cpp:9:6: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
  ss >> char(c);
  ~~ ^  ~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
$ ./a.out 
A
```

It prints out `A`, which is fine, given that this code shouldn't even compile. Switching to C++11 mode, it properly errors when compiling (`error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::stringstream' (aka 'basic_stringstream<char>') and 'int')`).

Yes, in C++03 mode it does give a warning, but it's not a warning I'd expect (I expected some kind of "taking temporary by reference" warning/error, or perhaps a warning/error saying no `operator>>` accepts a `char` parameter).

My question is: *why does the code successfully compile  in C++03 mode?* Is it using some alternative overload of `operator>>` that avoids taking the temporary by reference? Is it being overly lax and letting me take the temporary by reference? I'm puzzled at why clang accepts this code at all; GCC 4.9 properly errors out in C++03/11 modes with a much more relevant error (`error: no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'std::stringstream {aka std::basic_stringstream<char>}' and 'char')`). Clang's behavior in C++03 mode is puzzling me.

Comment: My version (`clang version 3.5.0 (tags/RELEASE_350/final), Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, Thread model: posix`) errors out properly, so it's possible that it is a bug that has been fixed.

Comment: I'd expect 5.1 to be later than 3.5.0. So if anything, it has been introduced, not fixed.

Comment: @celtschk 5.1 is Apple's version number. It's based off of 3.4svn, so 3.5 is newer.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar: Alternatively, it could be from a difference in libc++ vs libstdc++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it invokes the `operator bool()` of `std::stringstream`, that is, the code is interpreted as

```
bool(ss) >> char(c);
```

which of course is a valid statement with no effect. The implicit conversion to `bool` returns `!fail()` and is what allows code like

```
while (ss >> foo)
  ...
```

The standard allows to convert to another type that converts to `bool` instead of plain `bool` (for example a `void*`) exactly to avoid this type of problem. Apparently your implementation does not make use of that freedom.

Comment: Ah, that would make sense, especially since `operator bool()` was changed in C++11 to be `explicit`.