# C FILE* to ostream/istream

Tags: c++, c, io

I'm sorry if this is a question that's already come up, but I searched and couldn't find anything - is there a way in the C++ standard library to get an ostream (or an istream, depending on what you want) from a `FILE*`?

Something along the lines of

```
FILE* something;
auto out = hypothetical(something);
out << "Hello world" << std::endl;
```

Comment: Some ideas [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746168/how-to-construct-a-c-fstream-from-a-posix-file-descriptor).

Comment: This shouldn't have been marked a duplicate question IMO. I mean this question is asking about an interface in the C++ input/output library for making a stream from a FILE*. The other question was about making a stream from a POSIX int file descriptor. While the answers there apply, they do so more in a related sense IMO than a duplicate sense.

Comment: Incidentally perhaps, despite C++ recognizing [FILE*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/FILE), this is still (10 years after this was asked) a problem IMO in terms of the C++ standard input/output library. There are non standard interfaces in standard libc++ implementations like in gcc and clang that take POSIX file descriptors but not FILE* even though at least clang's implementation of streams uses FILE* under its hood. Which is also to say I share the OP's (Cubic's) interest in having a FILE* interface to C++ streams.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on compiler, you probably can just do the following:

```
FILE* f = fopen(myFile, "w+");
std::fstream myStream(f);
myStream << "Hello World\n";
```

Comment: The "depending on compiler" part kinda makes this a non-option for me. I'm writing non-toy programs that have to work cross platform and cross compiler.

Comment: Are you implying that all windows-only programs are "toy"? :)
Anyway, I did some research, and it seems to me, that there's no cross-platform solution.

Comment: No, I'm implying I'm writing cross platform applications that aren't toys.

Comment: This seems like a very reasonable extension/proposal to the C++ standard for `std::fstream` IMO. Sadly, it's not standard though at least through C++23.