# Redirecting console output/error of third party module to a log file

Tags: c++

in my application in c++, i am calling some other third party APIs which generates console output/error messages. i want to redirect all such messages to a log from my application so that user's screen just shows message of my application and is not filled with unrelated message from third party module.
Is there a way to do so. I am not sure but third party APIs is using c/c+_ libraries

Thanks
Ruchi

Comment: Are you on a specific platform? Is it acceptable to have the user start the application from a little wrapper script that redirects the output? (`#!/bin/bash \n ./myProg 2> logfile`).

Comment: No user should not see any change in the interface available to him. it should be a silent change in my application code. I am working on Linux. Also he should be able to see all the messages from my application on console only

Comment: Can you show us code where you are writing error on console?

Comment: How are you calling the third party API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you yourself don't use the standard output file descriptor, you can do this:

```
  int newout = dup(1);
  int log = open("./my.log", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 777);
  dup2 (log, 1);
```

Now the standard output (descriptor 1) goes to "./my.log", and the newout file descriptor goes to what used to be the standard output.

If you use Unix low-level IO (e.g. `write(2)`) you can use `newout` directly. If you use C stdio, `fdopen(3)` it. If you prefer C++ streams, look [at this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746168/how-to-construct-a-c-fstream-from-a-posix-file-descriptor).