# How to get file id from std::ofstream

Tags: c++, unix, filesystems

I want to use `flock(int fd, int operation)` on opened file, but `flock()` is `c` function. How to get `int fd` from `std::ofstream outfile` to use as argument for `flock()`.

ps. I want `int fd` at `c++` style, I know that I can open file in `c` style and get it.  The question is about `c++ and flock()`

```
std::ofstream outfile;
outfile.open ( LOCKFILE, std::ios_base::trunc);
```

thanks

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/a/5253726/2352671

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard way to get a file descriptor from a standard fstream. There may be a platform specific method, depending on your standard library implementation.

If you're using libstdc++ then according to [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2001-02/msg00120.html) there may be a `filedesc()` method on the fstream object that gives you what you want.

Comment: :( so, the only way to use locking is to use c style file open? ps. about your 'edit', seems it's not a good idea to use specific method for my system. I need method that will work on all unix systems.