# How can I open a file for reading & writing, creating it if it does not exist, without truncating it?

Tags: c++, iostream, fstream, c++03

What is the proper set of I/O flags for a `std::fstream`, where I want to be able to read from *and* write to the file, without truncating the file if it exists, but creating it if it does not?

I've tried

```
std::ios::binary | std::ios::in | std::ios::out
std::ios::binary | std::ios::in | std::ios::out | std::ios::ate
```

but neither of these create the file if it does not already exist.

I don't want `std::ios::app`, because I also need to be able to seek around the file at will, with both the *get* and *put* cursors.

One workaround, I suppose, would be to instantiate an `std::ofstream` first, then immediately close it and open the stream I really want, but that seems messy if it can be avoided with a single stream object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At this time, I'm concluding that `std::ios::in` outright prevents this, and that I must use the workaround.

So:

```
if (!std::ostream(path.c_str()))
   throw std::runtime_error("Could not create/open file");

std::fstream fs(path.c_str(), std::ios::binary | std::ios::in | std::ios::out);
if (!fs)
   throw std::runtime_error("Could not open file");

// ... use `fs`
```

Comment: You do not need failure checking or reporting for the creation attempt. Also, I think you don't need to use `c_str()` with C++11 and later. It's possible that Boost filesystem does this thing for you (I don't know), if so then you only have to wait till C++17. ;-)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf as-tagged (c++03), seems the reason for the `c_str()`, though you're clearly right if anyone reading this is going to do it with C++11 or later. Wasn't `std::string` construction included in 03x, btw?

Comment: @WhozCraig: No, the only new thing in C++03 was value initialization.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf ah..then all those `c_str` indeed make sense when coupled with that tag. thanks for the info!

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I realise I don't _need_ to check the first stream, but I'd rather have the more specific error message if creating the file fails. And, yeah, C++03 so the `.c_str()` is needed. :)

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit, I believe you forgot to add `std::ios::binary | std::ios::app` when you called the `std::ostream`  constructor. Without those flags the file will be truncated in case it already exists, which is something you said you did not want. And neither did I when I stumbled upon this :)

Answer (score 3):

An investigation, from a Linux perspective (though much of this likely applies to other Unices):

At the syscall layer, you want `open(O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0666)` (but not `O_TRUNC` or `O_APPEND` or a bunch of other flags, though arguably all files should be opened with `O_CLOEXEC | O_LARGEFILE`, but that's beside the point)

At the libc layer, there is no standard `mode` string that implies `O_CREAT` without `O_TRUNC`. However, you could use `open` followed by `fdopen`.

At the C++ library level, there is no standard way to pass the desired flags. However, using implementation-specific classes/functions or third-party libraries, it is possible; see [How to construct a c++ fstream from a POSIX file descriptor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746168/how-to-construct-a-c-fstream-from-a-posix-file-descriptor)

---

Personally, I tend to do all I/O at the C or even syscall level, since the API is a lot nicer and it's more predictable. For input/output of class instances, I have my own templates.

Answer (score -1):

Taking `std::ios::binary` as read, the remaining `openmode` probably you require is:

```
std::ios::in | std::ios::app
```

It's effect is as if to open the file with:

```
std::fopen(filename,"a+")
```

and the effect of *that* is:

- open or, if it does not exist, create the file for reading and writing
- write data at the end of the file.

If you open a file as an `std::fstream` with this `openmode`, it is not truncated if it exists. You may
read from the file wherever the `fstream`'s `tellg()\tellp()` pointer points,
provided there is something there to read, and you can position that pointer
with the stream's `seekg()\seekp()` for reading. However, all writes will be
appended to the end of the file.

This openmode will therefore fit your bill unless you need to perform writes
into existing data.

Comment: Thanks, close, but: _"I don't want `std::ios::app`, because I also need to be able to seek around the file at will, with both the get and put cursors."_