# How do I convert an io.Reader to a std::istream with SWIG & CGO?

Tags: c++, go, swig, istream, cgo

I'm trying to use SWIG to create a Go wrapper for a C++ API that uses `std::istream` to read binary data. I'd like to be able to pass an `io.Reader` to these APIs, but I'm not sure how to create a mapping between it and `std::istream`. I know I need to implement a `std::streambuf` subclass and I assume the rest will involve directors and typemaps, but I'm not familiar enough with SWIG to figure out the right combination.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Nope, not yet. Sorry!

Answer (score -1):

`io.Reader` is too general to be passed to C functions -- it might not be backed on a real file at all (it's just a class that implements a Read(...) function)

What you could do (so long as you aren't on windows) is use `os.Pipe()` to give you a ture FH object, but sadly the stock std::*stream doesn't have any way of creating a stream from an open file handle.

The pipe bit looks something like this:

```
func wrapReader(r io.Reader) uintptr {
    pr, pw, err := os.Pipe()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    go func () {
        _, _ io.Copy(pw, r)
        _ = pw.Close()
    }()

    return pr
}
```

If you combine that some of the code in this answer [How to construct a c++ fstream from a POSIX file descriptor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746168/how-to-construct-a-c-fstream-from-a-posix-file-descriptor#5253726) you might get what you need

Comment: `std::istream` is just an abstraction over a stream of bytes like `io.Reader`. Only the `std::ifstream` implementation actually deals with files.

Comment: True,true. It's more work but probably possible then to write an adapter  that calls back into go to read from the io.Reader. Getting the GC right so that the reader doesn't get destroyed under you is where most of the work might be then.

Comment: Well, since Go doesn't allow Go pointers to be passed to C code, the usual solution is to store the object in a map and pass the key back and forth. The object won't be GC'd until it's remove from the map. My question isn't so much about how to make the `std::streambuf`, but instead how to get SWIG to use that implementation whenever it encounters a C++ API that takes a `std::istream`.