# Sending data to a program via stdin and ostream. (C++)

Tags: c++, popen, ostream, filehandle

I would like to send data from within my C++ program to an external pipeline, like so:

```
FILE* file = popen("my_prog -opt | other_prog", "w");
std::ostream fileStream = some_function(file);
fileStream << "some data";
```

I understand there is no simple, cross-platform way to do the second line, but is there any way to accomplish the same thing using something other than `popen`? I don't need to use `popen`, but I do need to use `ostream`. It would need to compile with `clang` and `gcc` at minimum, but preferably it would work with any compiler. I could also change how I handle the piping, but I don't have the source for `my_prog` or `other_prog`.

Comment: Try to look at `boost::iostreams::file_descriptor`. It has very bad docs, but it can help you and it is cross-platform.

Comment: Is there any specific reason you *need* to use `ostream`

Comment: Can you put all your input into `fileStream` before creating the process, then feed that as input to `my_prog`, or is some of the input not known until after the process is created?

Comment: @James_Parsons There is a lot of other code in my codebase that works with `ostream`s.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I could easily tweak my program so that all of the input to the process is known at process creation time. Can you provide some code that shows how to connect the pipeline once I have done that?

Comment: Have you considered creating your own class that implements `std::ostream`? I am not sure about complexity but simple not-so-optimized version, as I guess, could be completed in one day. What I am sure about is that you shouldn't just write `popen` in your code: use RAII class with `popen` in constructor and `pclose` in destructor.

Comment: Would it be OK if it used an inherited class of `std::basic_ostream` ? `std::ostream` is not meant to be inherited from; all `std::basic_`* classes are.

Comment: The easiest soluton I could come up with would be to implement a custom `std::streambuf` that can be passed to the constructor of `std::ostream`. A short web search brought up [this site](http://www.mr-edd.co.uk/blog/beginners_guide_streambuf) which seems to already have code for `FILE*` that could easily be adjusted to work cross platform.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is straight forward to create a stream buffer using a `FILE*` as underlying destination and create a corresponding `std::ostream` using such a stream buffer. It would roughly look something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <streambuf>
#include <ostream>

class stdiobuf
    : public std::streambuf {
    enum { bufsize = 2048 };
    char buffer[bufsize];
    FILE* fp;
    int   (*close)(FILE*);
    int overflow(int c) {
        if (c != std::char_traits<char>::eof()) {
            *this->pptr() = std::char_traits<char>::to_char_type(c);
            this->pbump(1);
        }
        return this->sync()
            ? std::char_traits<char>::eof()
            : std::char_traits<char>::not_eof(c);
    }
    int sync() {
        std::streamsize size(this->pptr() - this->pbase());
        std::streamsize done(this->fp? fwrite(this->pbase(), 1, size, this->fp): 0);
        this->setp(this->pbase(), this->epptr());
        return size == done? 0: -1;
    }
public:
    stdiobuf(FILE* fp, int(*close)(FILE*) = fclose)
        : fp(fp)
        , close(close) {
        this->setp(this->buffer, this->buffer + (this->fp? bufsize - 1: 0));
    }
    ~stdiobuf() {
        this->sync();
        this->fp && this->close(this->fp);
    }
};
class opipestream
    : private virtual stdiobuf
    , public std::ostream {
public:
    opipestream(std::string const& pipe)
        : stdiobuf(popen(pipe.c_str(), "w"), pclose)
        , std::ios(static_cast<std::streambuf*>(this))
        , std::ostream(static_cast<std::streambuf*>(this)) {
    }
};

int main()
{
    opipestream out("/usr/bin/sed -e 's/^/xxxx /'");
    out << "Hello\n";
    out << "world\n";
}
```

The basic idea is that you can create a new stream by implementing a stream buffer. The implementation above should be fairly complete. The error handling when an incomplete buffer could be improved although the most likely case of an error is that the pipe was closed and there isn't really much what could be done.

Comment: Thank you this was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

My old answer did only work under Windows due to the missing `std::filebuf` ctor. As `user4815162342` pointed out that an alternative might be using `__gnu_cxx::stdio_filebuf<char>`.

I patched something together that should now work with windows and linux, yet there is a chance that your platforms might not all work.

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
    #include <ext/stdio_sync_filebuf.h>    
    typedef __gnu_cxx::stdio_sync_filebuf<char> popen_filebuf;
#elif _MSC_VER
    #include<fstream>
    typedef std::filebuf popen_filebuf;
    FILE*(*popen)(const char*, const char*) = _popen;
#else
    static_assert(false, "popen_filebuf is not available for this platform");
#endif

int main()
{
    FILE* file = popen("my_prog -opt | other_prog", "w");

    popen_filebuf buffer(file);
    std::ostream fileStream(&buffer);

    fileStream << "some data";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The standard doesn't mandate the `std::filebuf` is implemented in terms of `FILE*` although multiple implementation do (or did) it that way.

Comment: As shown in an edit of my answer, g++ on Linux also supports `__gnu_cxx::stdio_sync_filebuf`, so you can simply typedef `popen_filebuf` to `__gnu_cxx::stdio_sync_filebuf<char>`.

Comment: @user4815162342 That results in `error: no matching function for call to '__gnu_cxx::stdio_filebuf<char>::stdio_filebuf(FILE*&)'`

Comment: `stdio_filebuf` and `stdio_sync_filebuf` are different classes, and you need to use the latter (as shown in the comment) to directly construct from `FILE *`.

Comment: @user4815162342 Adjusted the answer. Thanks for the hint. It's much easier now.

Answer (score 3):

If you know in advance which platforms you support, you can use platform-specific extensions to create an iostream out of a file descriptor. For example, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746168/how-to-construct-a-c-fstream-from-a-posix-file-descriptor/5253726#comment37798114_5253726), GNU libstdc++ provides `__gnu_cxx::stdio_sync_filebuf` which can be used to create a `filebuf` from a `FILE *`. A class that inherits from `std::iostream` and initializes it with the appropriate `filebuf`, tested with g++ 5.2 and clang++ 3.7 on Linux, can look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ext/stdio_sync_filebuf.h>

class StdioStream:
  private __gnu_cxx::stdio_sync_filebuf<char>, public std::iostream {
public:
  explicit StdioStream(FILE *fp):
    __gnu_cxx::stdio_sync_filebuf<char>(fp), std::iostream(this) { }
};

int main()
{
    FILE* file = popen("my_prog -opt | other_prog", "w");
    StdioStream fileStream(file);
    fileStream << "some data";
}
```

Note that one cannot just define a `some_function` that returns an `std::ostream` because the latter has a private copy constructor, and because the intermediate `filebuf` needs to be destructed along with the stream. The above example uses multiple inheritance to be able to initialize `stdio_sync_filebuf` (which would otherwise be a member) before the `iostream` base class - see [base-from-member](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Base-from-Member) for details.

The referenced [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5253726/1600898) also contains equivalent code for MSVC++ iostreams.

Comment: why don't you derived from `std::iostream`?

Comment: @Walter Good point, I've now updated the answer to inherit from `iostream`. The [member-to-base](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Base-from-Member) problem requires multiple inheritance which reduces readability, but that buys simplicity of use for `StdioStream`, more than justifying the tradeoff.

Comment: @user4815162342 Why not combine our answers: http://rextester.com/PFJNUL66673 and http://goo.gl/NzKDeh

Comment: @SimonKraemer You kind of already did that, by incrementally editing your original answer to take the approach from mine. Now that Dietmar has provided a tested version of his portable answer, and his answer is accepted, the point is moot anyway.

Comment: @user4815162342 Ah - I didn't notice Dietmar's new answer. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

An expansion on my comment to the original question.

You can save all the input into a file on disk, then feed that file as input to `my_prog`.

```
ofstream fileStream("input.txt");
fileStream << "some data";
// insert other input
fileStream.close();
FILE *file = popen("my_prog -opt <input.txt | other_prog", "w");
```

You could use something other than popen here, possibly a straight `system` call.  Once you were all done, you'd want to delete the `input.txt` file.

Comment: While not portable, I've also seen ways of creating a process and using an alternative handle in place of stdin, stdout, etc., using native APIs .