# Always output to screen and allow redirection

Tags: c++, c

I'm writing a small CLI application and I want to allow the user to redirect to a file while standard cout statements go to the output.txt file I want progress to always to go the screen.

```
./myApp > output.txt
10% complete
...
90% complete
Completed
```

Is this possible?  How can I do it?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You can use `cerr` instead of `cout`, but that's kind of a subversion of its intent.

Comment: Well, it's a quite widespread one - I'm quite sure that curl (as well as many other common tools) do that.

Comment: @MarkRansom – I tried std::cerr << "% complete" and that did not work.  The output was still redirected to the users file.

Comment: I take that back... std::err << "% complete" worked.  I missed a spot which caused me to believe it had NOT worked.  Thanks... This is great and doesn't require the users to know about any special things to do.

Comment: Instead of messing with stdout and detecting terminals you may pipe your output through `tee` utility that does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 2):

This will work even if both **stdin** and **stdout** have been redirected:

```
spectras@etherbee:~$ ./term
hello terminal!
spectras@etherbee:~$ ./term >/dev/null 2>&1
hello terminal!
```

The idea is to open the controlling terminal of the process directly, bypassing any redirection, like this:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int fd = open("/dev/tty", O_WRONLY);
    if (fd < 0 && errno != ENODEV) {
        /* something went wrong */
        return 1;
    }
    int hasTTY = (fd >= 0);

    if (hasTTY) {
        write(fd, "hello terminal!\n", 16);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

From `man 4 tty`:

> The  file  /dev/tty  is  a  character file with major number 5 and
>   minor number 0, usually of mode 0666 and owner.group root.tty.  It is
>   a synonym for the controlling terminal of a process, if any.

If you're using C++, you might want to wrap the file descriptor into a custom streambuf, so you can use regular stream API on it. Alternately, some implementations of the C++ library offer extensions for that purpose. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746168/how-to-construct-a-c-fstream-from-a-posix-file-descriptor).
Or, if you don't care about getting the error code reliably, you could just `std::ofstream terminal("/dev/tty")`.

Also as a design consideration if you do this, offering a quiet option to let the user turn off the writing to the terminal is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Your process cannot know if the shell redirects the standard console output (`std::cout`) or not.

So you'll need another handle that lets you output to the terminal independently of that redirection.

As @Mark mentioned in [their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45766107/always-output-to-screen-and-allow-redirection#comment78490722_45766107) you could (ab-)use<sup>1</sup> `std::cerr` to do that, along with some ASCII trickery to overwrite the current output line at the terminal (look at backspace characters: `'\b'`).

---

<sup>1)</sup><sub>Not to mention the mess printed at the terminal if the output isn't actually redirected.</sub>

Comment: Actually, usually you *can* know if you are writing on a terminal or not - on POSIX systems the `isatty` function exists just for this reason (typically utilities use it to disable ASCII escapes for formatting when the output is not going to a terminal).

Comment: @MatteoItalia Bit of offleg for standard c++  though. But thanks for adding that information.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it, even if the user redirects `stderr`. The following code gets the name of the current terminal and checks to see if our output is being redirected. It also has a my_write() function that allows you to write to both the terminal and the redirect file, if they've redirected `stdout`. You can use the my_write() function with the `writetoterm` variable where-ever you want to write something that you want to *always* be written to the terminal. The `extern "C"` *has* to be there, otherwise (on Debian 9 with GCC 6.3, anyway) the `ttyname()` function will just return `NULL` all the time.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <error.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sstream>

using std::string;
using std::fstream;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cerr;
using std::stringstream;

void my_write(bool writetoterm, int termfd, string data)
{
    if(writetoterm)
    {
        int result = write(termfd, data.c_str(), data.length());
        if(result < data.length()){
            cerr << "Error writing data to tty" << endl;
        }
    }
    cout << data;
}

extern "C" {
char* GetTTY(int fd){
    //printf("%s", ttyname(fd));
    return ttyname(fd);
}
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    getenv("TTY");
    bool writetoterm = false;
    struct stat sb = {};

    if(!GetTTY(STDOUT_FILENO)){
        //not a TTY
        writetoterm = true;
    }
    int ttyfd = open(GetTTY(2), O_WRONLY);
    if(ttyfd < 0){
        //error in opening
        cout << strerror(errno) << endl;
    }
    string data = "Hello, world!\n";
    my_write(true, ttyfd, data);

    int num_for_cout = 42;
    stringstream ss;
    ss << "If you need to use cout to send something that's not a string" << endl;
    ss << "Do this: " << num_for_cout << endl;
    my_write(writetoterm, ttyfd, ss.str().c_str());

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That plain doesn't work. The `FIONREAD` ioctl is used to know whether a file descriptor has data ready. Here, the stdin one. This is completely unrelated to whether stdout, stderr or both have been redirected.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your progress indicators to the `stderr` stream.  They will appear on the console if the user redirects `stdout` to a file.

For example:

```
fprintf(stderr, "10%% complete\n");
```

Comment: – I tried std::cerr << "% complete" and that did not work. The output was still redirected to the users file.

Answer (score 0):

I found the official std:: method of handling this.  There is another type... std::clog.  This is specifically for information and always appears on the command line even though the user redirects the output of the program myProgram > out.txt.

Thanks this was great to see all the methods that this can be done.