# cin.tellg returns -1 when receiving input from a pipe

Tags: c++, linux, fork, exec

I have a case where I need pipe the output of a child process to an `ifstream`.

I am trying both creating an ifstream from a file descriptor using the method here: [How to construct a c++ fstream from a POSIX file descriptor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746168/how-to-construct-a-c-fstream-from-a-posix-file-descriptor)

and I am also trying to just use a pipe from the child stderr to my own stdin and using cin as my stream.

In both cases I am getting -1 when I call tellg.

Here is my code with the pipe from child stderr to parent stdin:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

using namespace std;

int
main()
{
    int mypipe[2];

    pipe(mypipe);

    dup2(mypipe[0], STDIN_FILENO);
    dup2(mypipe[1], STDERR_FILENO);

    __pid_t pid = fork();

    if(pid == 0)
    {
        // this is a process that outputs stuff into std::err
        char* argv[] = {"copy-feats", nullptr};

        int ret = execvp(argv[0], argv);

        exit(ret);
    }

    int status;
    waitpid(pid, &status, WNOHANG);

    cin.clear(); // attempting to clear the error state. Not working.
    long size = cin.tellg();
    cout << size << endl;
}
```

so as I said the output of tellg is -1.

thought if I try to use getline(cin, some_string) I'll actually be able to see the output of the child program.

I tried creating a stream from a pipe, but it still gives me -1.

Here's the code I used:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <ext/stdio_filebuf.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define READ_FD  0
#define WRITE_FD 1

using namespace std;

using FilebufType = __gnu_cxx::stdio_filebuf<std::ifstream::char_type>;

int
main()
{
    int mypipe[2];

    pipe(mypipe);

    __pid_t pid = fork();

    if(pid == 0)
    {
        dup2(mypipe[WRITE_FD], STDERR_FILENO);
        char* argv[] = {"copy-feats", nullptr};

        int ret = execvp(argv[0], argv);

        exit(ret);
    }

    int status;
    waitpid(pid, &status, WNOHANG);

    FilebufType filebuf(mypipe[READ_FD], std::ios::in);
    istream is(&filebuf);

    is.clear();
    auto size = is.tellg();
    cout << size << endl;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Of course you're getting -1 from `tellg()`. Pipes are not seekable, and there is no such thing as a "file position" when it comes to a pipe. Only actual physical files are physical, and provide a file position. Only `std::ifstream`s provide file position indication, when attached to a real file.

Comment: Look up what that return value means.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thank you that answers my question. I suggest you post it as an answer, to make it clearer to future visitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In practice `tellg()` returns an actual file position only when the input stream is a real file. That is, when the input stream is a `std::ifstream`, and then only when the underlying file is a plain file.

Pipes, and other non-plain files don't have a concept of a file position.

On Linux, which you are using, `tellg()` is typically implemented (indirectly, but that's not relevant here) by using `lseek(2)`, and [`lseek(2)`'s documentation](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman2/lseek.2.html) explicitly specifies that it returns an `ESPIPE` error if the file descriptor is a pipe. And an error return, eventually, translates to `tellg()` returning -1.